# Restrict access to .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, security, dll, assemblies, namespaces

Is there a way to have a .NET assembly accessible for only authorized sources?

I mean I want to have a DLL that contains components, but I don't want anyone to be able to use these components but the other DLLs EXEs in my solution.
I do want them to be in separated DLLs though.

Restriction on namespace might also be a good idea if this feature exists out there.

Is there a way?

Comment: is using the OSes Access Control List OK? Get the user and check access to some known file, dir, etc...

Comment: ANYTHING is welcommed, please post an answer of your idea, so people can vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create internal classes.  And the give your specified assemblies to access these classes by using [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

The assembly should be strong named.  You can find more information about the attribute in [this article](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2007/12/09/testing-internals-members-with-internalsvisibleto-attribute/).

Comment: See also http://www.bryancook.net/2008/05/tdd-tips-internalsvisibleto-keep-your.html

Answer (score 5):

The problem with Internal classes is Internal has no meaning in IL and the classes can be called via reflection. So using InternalsVisibleTo is more a helper for the compiler than anything else.

You can go one step further using the [StrongNameIdentityPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.strongnameidentitypermission%28VS.71%29.aspx) which will check the public key of the strong named assembly calling into the code - if the public key doesn't match then a security exception is thrown. This is enforced even when code is called via reflection.