# Scope Modifiers

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, scope

I have 2 projects:

1. A Class Library that contains my
   classes/business logic
2. A WPF
       application that uses the Class
       Library (DLL)

I have been given the task of hiding all of the Class Library functions and classes so that it cannot be called or used by external applications.

My problem is that the WPF application is an "external application".

I changed all Public scope modifiers for all of the classes and properties to Friend.

I then tried combining both projects into one solution...which of course didn't work.
Within the solution that contains both projects, I also tried changing the "Assembly" of the Class Library to match the WPF (Because "Friend" allows code within the same assembly to use it)...but this doesn't work either.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

-Frinny

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict access to .NET assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416190/restrict-access-to-net-assembly)

Comment: I didn't think to search for "restrict access to .NET assembly"....mind you this question is starting to become much larger now that I have more information about the InternalsVisibleTo attribute and also more information on CAS (etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I am checking out the documentation now :)  :)

Comment: Quick question: how do I find the PublicKey of my application? At the bottom of the article the suggest to use the Sn.exe utility...and then if you go through the links you are told to use Visual Studio's Command Line tool...but even though I have VS2010 installed, I do not have the Visual Studio command line tool...

Comment: This really should be a new question, but Visual Studio's Command Line tool is nothing else than "Visual Studio Command Prompt" in the program group "Microsoft Visual Studio <Version>\Visual Studio Tools"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know why that tool is not installed. I'm looking into finding the installation DVD now.

Comment: @Frinavale: The target of that link is `%comspec% /k ""C:\Programme\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86`

Comment: @Frinavale, have you signed your application with a key?  If not then you don't need to provide the public key part, just the name.

Comment: Wow, Daniel I could have used that about a half an hour ago!!! It took me that long to find out that you have to open command line, navigate to "...\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC" and run the vcvarsall.bat command (passing it the correct argument)

Comment: @Frinavale: Well... I actually posted it 26 minutes ago ;-)

Comment: I gave this a try. And apparently @Sam Holder was correct in that you don't need to sign the application (if you don't then you can just use the assembly name). I ran into problems with with using Friend though. While the VB.NET code in my WPF application can access the Friend classes, the WPF XAML portion doesn't seem to be be able to bind-to/show the information.  I'm back to square 1 now.

Answer (score 2):

If they are different assemblies, then there is no direct way to do that. You can get a bit cheeky with `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`, but that is a bit hacky.

Frankly, you can't stop external code calling your methods unless you go to extremes. A malicious app can just ***walk past any modifiers*** with reflection if they want (since the app *calling* you probably owns the AppDomain, it can assert full-trust). There is some support for caller-based security / permissions, but the *regular* stuff is largely disabled by "full trust" - you would need to check the caller yourself. Not worth it, IMO. Especially since from 4.0 code-access permissions are not used any more (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.strongnameidentitypermission%28v=VS.100%29.aspx))

Comment: The link you posted lead me into the huge topic of CAS. I am looking over the Security Changes in the .NET 4 Framework now (http://bit.ly/a4Hchz). In .NET 4 they have changed things around and removed some methods but the feature is still there. What I don't understand is how policies and run time demands are going to prevent people from adding a reference to my DLL in their project and seeing all of the classes and their members...? Sorry for my ignorance (I am very new to this), but could you please clarify what you're talking about?

Comment: I think that a combination of using the InternalsVisibleTo Attribute and CAS (to some extent) is what I am looking for. Thank you @Marc Gravell for pointing out some valuable information that I would not have considered.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to set the [InternalsVisibleTo attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) so that the internal classes are visible to your WPF application, and this will allow it to still se them but other apps will not be able to.

Some help with it [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweblogs.asp.net%2Fbhouse%2Farchive%2F2006%2F04%2F17%2F443100.aspx&ei=HHZ_TZO9NcPG0QGDvpH1CA&usg=AFQjCNFJokhcRDWD6-cpwSGor5mCTAqarg&sig2=p9ElvUPrsoippkI5d6SE9A)

As has been mentioned, this will work for only the most simple of situations.  People will still be able to call your methods using reflection if they want.